# Result set returning less number of rows than actual result

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I am developing web application to know table hierarchy in SQL Server.
Following code is to show List of all tables present in the database.

```
        String dbServer = session.getAttribute("dbServer").toString();
        String dbUsername = session.getAttribute("dbUsername").toString();
        String dbPassword = session.getAttribute("dbPassword").toString();
        String connectionUrl = session.getAttribute("connectionUrl").toString();

        String dbName = session.getAttribute("dbName").toString();

        out.println("<h2>Database : " + dbName + "</h2>");

        Connection con = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        try {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl, dbUsername, dbPassword);

            String listAllTablesQuery = "select TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where TABLE_TYPE='base table' order by TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME";

            stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);

            rs = stmt.executeQuery(listAllTablesQuery);

            rs.last();
            System.out.println("Count : "+rs.getRow());
            rs.beforeFirst();

    %>

    <h3>
        List of Tables present in
        <%=dbName%>
        Database
    </h3>
    <table border=3>
        <tr>
            <th>Schema Name</th>
            <th>Table Name</th>
        </tr>
        <%
            String tableInfoUrl = "TableInfo.jsp?tableName=";

                while (rs.next()) {
                    out.println("<tr><td>" + rs.getString(1) + "</td><td><a target=_blank href=" + tableInfoUrl
                            + rs.getString(2) + "&schemaName=" + rs.getString(1) + ">" + rs.getString(2)
                            + "</a></td></tr>");
                }

                rs = null;
        %>

    </table>
    <%  
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (rs != null)
                try {
                    rs.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            if (stmt != null)
                try {
                    stmt.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            if (con != null)
                try {
                    con.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
        }
```

I am getting 64 rows in the result set that also only for dbo schema. But If I execute given query in ssms I am getting 1701 rows. If we consider tables under dbo then also there are 1219 tables. I don't understand why there are only 64 rows present in the result set??

Comment: Have you tried `select count(*) from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where TABLE_TYPE='base table'  ` in Java/JSP? What is the result?

Comment: is your user have correct privileges ?

Comment: @zhliu03 I did not try select count(*) because I need table and schema name as output. I am focusing on counter just to see how many tables are missing.

Comment: @sanjeev : as it is showing 64 rows correctly, I think user have required privileges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was happening because database name was not present in the connectionUrl. 
Now it is working as per expectations. Thank you all :)

Answer (score 0):

Is the user that you use to connect to DB from your web application the same with the user that you use in ssms? If it is different check to which tables the user you use to connect from your web application has permissions.

Comment: Yes username I used in the application is exactly same which I use to connect Db through ssms